# Reference request for a "well-known identity" in a paper of Shepp and Lloyd

Tags: pr.probability, gamma-function, reference-request

I ran into a "well-known identity" on page 345 of Shepp and Lloyd's [On ordered cycle lengths in a random permutation](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1994483):
$$\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-y)}y dy = \int_0^x \frac{1-\exp(-y)}y dy - \log x - \gamma, $$
 where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant. I am clueless as to how it is derived. Any reference to the derivation of such formulae would suffice, but an explicit solution will also be appreciated.

Comment: This refers to an earlier question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19392/generalized-binomial-coefficients-and-gaussian-density

Comment: A link to an online copy of the paper (preferably not behind a paywall) would be highly appropriate here.

Comment: I added a JSTOR link. The article is also at http://ifile.it/tfja0wc, but the link is probably temporary.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/313/when-a-paper-is-behind-a-paywall/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply WZ theory to such identities.  In particular, both sides satisfy
$$x*z''(x) + (x+1)z'(x)$$
Picking $x=1$ as the initial condition (since the DE is regular there, that helps), we see that both sides evaluate to $Ei(1,1)$ and their derivatives both evaluate to $-1/e$, so they are equal.

I got that differential equation using Maple's *PDEtools[dpolyform]* function, which uses Groebner bases over differential polynomials to 'solve' this problem.  All the rest is classical analysis (as in [A course of modern analysis](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521588072) by Whittaker and Watson, 1926 - which is unfortunately not material that is taught very much anymore, I certainly had to learn a lot of that 'on my own').

[Edit: fixed an error in the evaluation of the derivative, I pasted in the wrong line]

Comment: Yes that's a tremendously rich text much of which I am not familiar with. Thanks for the hard work!

Comment: What is "WZ theory"?

Comment: Wilf-Zeilberger, probably, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf-Zeilberger_pair

Comment: @Reid: correct.

Answer (score 2):

This identity appears on the Wikipedia page for the "exponential integral":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definition_by_Ein

I imagine you can get it by integrating the Taylor series and playing around.  Wikipedia, and several other places on the web, point to the book by Abramovitz and Stegun.

Comment: Thanks for the nice reference on wiki! I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: You can prove the identity up to a constant factor by differentiating with respect to x, so it only remains to prove it for x = 1.  This should be a little easier.

Comment: Indeed, it makes it a lot easier. Using integration by part, one can show that 
$\int_1^{\infty} \exp(-y)/y dy - \int_0^1 \frac{1-\exp(-y)}{y}dy = \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-y) \log y dy
which is listed as equal to $-\gamma$ in the following wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals

I am yet to figure out why that formula in the wiki page is true.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log t\,dt$
equals $\Gamma'(1)$. This can be evauated as $-\gamma$
using the infinite product for the gamma function.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I will  write a short summary of the proof combining all the ingredients given so far.

Answer (score 2):

So one of the approaches to proving the equality in the question is via the following three steps:
  First differentiate both sides of the equation to see that they agree up to a constant. This reduces to showing the case of $x = 1$, for which $\log x = 0$.

Next we apply integration by parts to get
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \exp(-y)/y dy - \int_0^1 \frac{1-\exp(-y)}{y}dy = \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-y) \log y dy 
$$

Finally observe that $\Gamma'(1)$ equals the RHS, by differentiating under the integral sign, valid because things are decaying fast enough at infinity.

So it remains to show $\Gamma'(1) =\gamma$. I saw a soft argument (i.e., without using infinite product) in the link scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/psifun_10.pdf
This is re-exposed below:

first we establish that for $\Psi(x) = \log \Gamma(x)$,
$$
\Psi'(x+1) = \Psi'(x) + 1/x
$$
This is easy enough since we have we have the functional equation $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$.
Next using stirling approximation we get

$$
\Psi(x+1) = (x+1/2)\log x -x + 1/2 \log 2 \pi + O(1/x)
$$
and then they differentiate this and claim that $O(1/x)' = O(1/x^2)$, which is clearly false (take $f(x) = 1/x cos(e^x)$). But I found in Wikipedia another formula that gives the precise error term in terms of an integral of the monotone function $arctan(1/x)$. So this is enough to establish $O(1/x^2)$ for the error term in the derivative of $\Psi$. So we get the asymptotics $\lim_{x \to \infty} \Psi'(x+1) = \log(x)$, from which we get $\Psi'(1) = \gamma$. Now notice $\Psi'(x) = \Gamma'(x)/ \Gamma(x)$, and $\Gamma(1) = 1$, so $\Gamma'(1) = \gamma$ also.